# Get object after open modal with @Input directive from component

Tags: angular, input, components, angular7, angular8

I want get object when open Modal component and get the value passed from component.

So this is my method inside `UserComponent.ts` to open `ModifyuserModalComponent`:

```
  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  modifyUser(user: UteUser) {
    console.log(user); //this print correctlry my object
    this.dialog.open(ModifyuserModalComponent, {
      data: user
    });
  }
```

and this my ModifyuserModalComponent ts code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modifyuser-modal',
  templateUrl: './modifyuser-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modifyuser-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ModifyuserModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModifyuserModalComponent>
  ) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("usergetted: ", this.data);
  }

  closeDialog(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

So my target is get `data` from `UserComponent.ts` when I click to open dialog.
But when open `ModifyuserComponent` my data object is **undefined**.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.dialog.open(ModifyuserModalComponent, {
  data: user
});
```

returns a `MatDialogRef`, on which in turn you can access the instantiated component.

Therefore this will work:

```
const modalRef = this.dialog.open(ModifyuserModalComponent, {
  data: user
});
const modal = modalRef.componentInstance
modal.data... // your code goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

share data using service and Observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(message: string) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }

    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

in ModifyuserModalComponent subscribe to following method:
 this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message; });